# Measurability of diagonal partitions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measure space and $\Pi$ a partition of $\Omega$. Let $\Pi(\omega)$ denote the partition element containing $\omega$. I want to know when is the set $\bigcup_{\omega\in\Omega}\Pi(\omega)\times\Pi(\omega)$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}$. More concretely, let $\Omega$ be the Cantor space and $\mathcal{F}$ the sigma-algebra generated by cylinders (sets of binary strings that agree on their first $n$ coordinates, for some $n$). Let $\Pi$ be the partition of $\Omega$ into sets of strings that agree eventually (i.e. they only disagree on finitely many coordinates). E.g. if $0$ denotes the constant $0$ sequence, then $\Pi(0)$ is the set of strings that are eventually $0$. I would like to know if $\bigcup_{\omega\in\Omega}\Pi(\omega)\times\Pi(\omega)$ is an element of $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $A = \cup_{\omega \in \Omega} \Pi(\omega) \times \Pi(\omega)$. $A$ is in fact measurable. To show this define $\phi: \Omega \times \Omega \to \Omega$ by
$$ \phi(\omega^1, \omega^2)_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\ \omega^1_i = \omega^2_i \\ 0 & \text{if}\ \omega^1_i \neq \omega^2_i. \end{cases} $$
This is measurable since each coordinate of $\phi$, $\phi_i: \Omega \times \Omega \to \{0, 1\}$, is measurable (just check by brute force). Then note that
$$ A = \phi^{-1} (\Pi(1, 1, 1, \ldots)). $$
So to show $A$ is measurable, it suffices to argue that $\Pi(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is measurable. In fact $\Pi(\omega)$ is measurable for any $\omega$. By countable intersections, the set of $\omega'$ agreeing with $\omega$ from the $n$th coordinate onwards is measurable for any $n$. Then just take the countable union over all $n$ to show $\Pi(\omega)$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks! This is an ingenious method!