# Is $1_{\Pi(x)}(y)$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory

This question is related to a previous question I asked here ([Measurability of diagonal partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324003/measurability-of-diagonal-partitions/3324681#3324681)). Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be the Cantor space equipped with the algebra generated by sets of strings that agree on their first $n$ coordinates. Let $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be the function that projects $x\in\Omega$ to its n-th coordinate $x(n)$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the tail-sigma-algebra $\bigcap_n\mathcal{G}_n$, where $\mathcal{G_n}=\sigma\{X_m: m\geq n\}$. One can check that the atoms of $\mathcal{G}$ are sets of strings that agree except on finitely many coordinates.

My question is: is the function $(w,v)\mapsto 1_{\Pi(w)}(v)$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{F}$? I think I have a proof that suggests no, but I am wondering if there is a more straightforward reasoning.

The proof I had in mind is as follows: suppose $f(w,v)=1_{\Pi(w)}(v)$ is measurable. Let $P$ be the fair coin measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $Q:\mathcal{F}\times\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$ be the map $Q(A,w)=P(A)$. It is well-known that $Q$ is a regular conditional probability of $P$ given $\mathcal{G}$. Now, note that $P$ can be viewed as a product measure $P'$ on $\Omega\times\Omega$ with $P'(A\times B)=P(A\cap B)$. Moreover, $P'=PT^{-1}$, where $T:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega\times\Omega$ is the diagnoal map $w\mapsto (w,w)$. By change of variables, $\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}fdP'=\int_\Omega f\circ TdP=1$ since $f\circ T(w)=1$ for all $w$. However, by Fubini-Tonelli, $\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}fdP'=\int_\Omega [\int_\Omega f(w,v)\mu_w(dv)]P(dw)=\int P(\Pi(w))P(dw)=0$. So we had a contradiction.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone has more intuitions about why $f$ is non-measurable (assuming the proof above is correct). Equivalently, why the set $\bigcup_{w\in\Omega}\Pi(w)\times\Pi(w)$ is not an element of $\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{F}$.